# Run command in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create my first page in Symfony2 according to this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/page_creation.html. Can anyone please tell how should I run this command:

```
php app/console init:bundle "Acme\StudyBundle" src
```

I'm new to symfony and I have no idea what this means...

Comment: Do you have command-line access to the computer you are building the tutorial site on?

Comment: ./app/console is php executable script similar to ./symfony in symfony 1.4, you use it to do some handle some tasks like generation of application structure, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php app/console init:bundle "Acme\StudyBundle" src
```

is a shell command you're meant to run at the command line of the machine you've installed Symfony on. You change into the directory where you installed symfony, and run it -- how you do that is obviously operating system- and installation-dependent.

The command itself invokes the command-line version of your PHP interpreter (`php`) to run Symfony's `console` script (`app/console`) to initialise a new Symfony bundle (`init:bundle`) called StudyBundle, from the ([pretend!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation)) company Acme (`Acme\StudyBundle`) in the directory `src`.

For me, running it would look a bit like this (from Terminal, on a Mac):

```
Matt-Gibsons-iMac:~ matt$ cd Sites/Symfony 
Matt-Gibsons-iMac:Symfony matt$ php app/console init:bundle "Acme\StudyBundle" src
Summary of actions
- The bundle "AcmeStudyBundle" was created at "src/Acme/StudyBundle" and is using the namespace "Acme\StudyBundle".
...
```

A word of warning, though: Symfony 2 is still very new -- not yet even officially released -- and while what documentation there is is okay, the docs are nothing like as complete or helpful to the beginner as the excellent, mature documentation for Symfony 1.4. Also, Symfony 2 best practices have yet to be established.

So, if you're a complete Symfony novice you might find Symfony 1.4 easier going, especially following the [Jobeet](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/) tutorial. Even though Symfony 2 is quite a big change from Symfony 1, learning Symfony 1 will introduce you to a lot of concepts that remain familiar in Symfony 2, such as generating new code modules from the command line, like you're trying to do here.